Sommerfeld expansion and transport theory
In my lecture of condensed matter theory, we are studying the transport theory. In doing so, we initially considered integrals of the following type, which according to the lecturer, will come in handy later on:
$K^{(n)}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\epsilon \epsilon^n \sigma(\epsilon)\frac{df(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}$
where $f(\epsilon)$ is the Fermi function for chemical potential μ and temperature T.
$\sigma(\epsilon)$ satisfies the following: $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow -\infty}\epsilon^n\sigma(\epsilon)=0$.
He proceeds by saying that, if we use the Sommerfeld expansion we can expresse elements such as $K^{(0)}$, $K^{(1)}$ etc. in terms of the chemical potential $\mu$ and derivatives of $\sigma(\epsilon)$ evaluated at $\mu$.
But I am confused as to how we can use the Sommerfeld expansion here.
From what I know, the Sommerfeld expansion can be used firstly when you are in the limits of low temperature, which here it is not stated. And secondly, when we were asked to derive the Sommerfeld expansion, the integral considered had $f(\epsilon)$ as an argument and not $(f(\epsilon))^2$, which is what one gets if he were to perform $\frac{f(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}$.
And even in the wikipedia article the Sommerfeld expansion considers $f(\epsilon)$.
So am I missing something here? How exactly one can perform a Sommerfeld expansion and gain i.e. $K^{(1)}$?

I strongly suspect that your integral should be
$
K^{(n)} = \int d \epsilon , \epsilon^n , \sigma(\epsilon), \left(\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\right)^n ! f(\epsilon)
$

It was given as I wrote it above though. Is there a name for what you wrote?

Just the Taylor expansion of $f(\epsilon)$ around $\epsilon = 0$.
